# EaselJS grid drawing is strangely offset/scaled

Tags: javascript, canvas, easeljs, createjs

This code is supposed to draw a grid (it's meant for a maze, so I need to only draw parts of it):

```
function drawMaze() {
for (var r = 0; r < Rows.length; r++) {
    var row = Rows[r];
    var sr = new createjs.Shape();
    sr.x = 0;
    sr.y = (r + 1) * offY;
    var gr = sr.graphics.beginStroke("black");
    gr.moveTo(0, (r + 1) * offY);
    for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        if (row[i] === true) {
            console.log("r=" + r + ",i=" + i + ",x=" + (i + 1) * offX + ",y=" + (r + 1) * offY);
            gr.lineTo((i + 1) * offX, (r + 1) * offY);
        } else {
            gr.moveTo((i + 1) * offX, (r + 1) * offY);
        }
    }
    stage.addChild(sr);
}
for (var c = 0; c < Cols.length; c++) {
    var col = Cols[c];
    var sc = new createjs.Shape();
    sc.x = (c + 1) * offX;
    sc.y = 0;
    var gc = sc.graphics.beginStroke("black");
    gc.moveTo((c + 1) * offX, 0);
    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
        if (col[i] === true) {
            console.log("c=" + c + ",i=" + i + ",x=" + (c + 1) * offX + ",y=" + (i + 1) * offY);
            gc.lineTo((c + 1) * offX, (i + 1) * offY);
        } else {
            gc.moveTo((c + 1) * offX, (i + 1) * offY);
        }
    }
    stage.addChild(sc);
}
var sd = new createjs.Shape();
sd.graphics.s("black").mt(0, 0).lt(offX * Cols.length, offY * Rows.length).f("red").r(175,175,175,175);
stage.addChild(sd);
stage.update();
}
```

The diagonal line/red square is only for visualization.
With this, the spacing between rows/columns is doubled and so only half of the lines form a grid. Here is the full code: http://jsfiddle.net/vyLRT/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out what was wrong! I just simply moved the lines twice.

So instead of

```
sr.x = 0;
sr.y = (r + 1) * offY;

sc.x = (c + 1) * offX;
sc.y = 0;
```

all values just need to be set to 0.